# How put the json data to foreign key of a table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, post

I have two entities.

**Task**

```
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String tilte;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id")
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="task_status_id")
    private TaskStatus taskStatus;

}
```

**Project**

```
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

When I create a new task I send post request but have problem with `project_id`. I think that my mapping has some problem because request has written rightly.

ERRORS:
[WARN ] 2018-01-27 00:08:41.103 engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper                                     logExceptions                           (129  )
                    - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
[ERROR] 2018-01-27 00:08:41.104 engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper                                     logExceptions                           (131  )
                    - Column 'project_id' cannot be null

It's example my JSON post requst:

{"name":newTask,"title":"newTaskTitle","project":[{"id":1,"name":"projectName"}], "taskStatus":
[{"id":1, "name":"taskStatusName"}]}

Comment: Please, add description of error which you get. Also, JPA soesn't operate with get/post, which hints me that context is not full.

Comment: I edited quastion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it's because your DB's project_id FK is set to not nullable you have the @JsonIgnore annotation to your Project attribute; You do send the project in your JSON request, but it's simply being ignore by Hibernate/JPA so it stays null and violates your non-nullable DB constraint. Moreover, if the DB field is not nullable, I would suggest you add "nullable=false" to your JoinColumn just in case Hibernate/JPA tries to do something funny.

If you DO remove the annotation, you most probably will get into a DetachedEntityException of some sort. Bidirectional are a conceptually nice, but a pain to deal with in both JSON and Hibernate; you can check [my answer to a very similar question/problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472100/4660500).