# Spring - POSTing JSON body with nested entity does not work

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring and java, so apologises if this is obvious.

**TLDR**
When I send JSON with nested resources, it creates the subresource. EVEN when it already exists, causing a persistence issue, how do you stop this in Spring?

I have two entities, Book and Shelf. A shelf can have multiple books but a book can only be on one shelf. So Shelf (1) <-> (*) Book.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "shelf_id"))
    private Shelf shelf;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(UUID id, String name, String description, Shelf shelf) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.shelf = shelf;
    }


    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setShelf(Shelf shelf) {
        this.shelf = shelf;
    }
}
```

Shelf

```
@Entity
public class Shelf {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "shelf", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Book> books;

    public Dashboard() {
    }

    public Dashboard(UUID id, String name, String description, Set<Book> books) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.book = book;
    }


    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setBooks() {
        for (Book book : books)
            book.setShelf(this);
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
}
```

I have a ShelfRepository which extends JpaRepository.

When I make a request with the body

```
{"name":"ShelfName", "books": [{"name": "bookName"}]}
```

it will return create the resource Book and Shelf but does not link them as Book is created first without Shelf to reference. So calling setBooks on the Shelf is needed. Not ideal but I cant figure out another way.

Creating a book and using the id as the reference in the books array (which is what I would like in my API) like below:

```
{"name":"otherShelfName", "books": [{"id": "7d9c81c2-ac25-46ab-bc4d-5e43c595eee3"}]}
```

This causes a persistence issue as the book already exist

*org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist*

Is there a way to have a nested resource like above in Spring and be able to associate without a persistence issue?

-------- Services

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Book create(Book book) {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class ShelfService {

    @Autowired
    private ShelfRepository shelfRepository;

    public List<Shelf> findAll() {
        return shelfRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Book create(Book book) {
        Shelf newShelf = shelfRepository.save(shelf);
        shelf.setBooks();
        return newShelf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the painful ... ehhh I meant wondeful ... world of ORMs where doing simple things is trivial, but doing things even a tad complicated becomes increasingly complicated :P

Few pointers that might help:

- If a book HAS to belong to a shelf, the @JoinColumn should probably also have nullable=false; this should force Hibernate to persiste the shelf first since it will need the ID to persist the book's shelf_id FK.
- You have a bidirectional relationship which, in a way, can be seen as an infinite loop (shelf contains books, that references shelf, that contains books, that ...); there are ways to handle that using Jackson, you can read about it [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).
- Going back to both points above, although your shelf contains books in your JSON data, that same data doesn't explicitly have the book point back to shelf AND, from an Hibernate perspective the relationship is optional anyway so it probably just didn't bother doing the link.
- Now the "nullable=false" trick might solve all of that if you are lucky, but nothing is ever easy so I would doubt it; as I said before, if you look only at the JSON for books, they have no references to the parent shelf so when Jackson converts the books to Java object, the "shelf" property most probably stays null (but you cannot reference the shelf's ID since it wasn't created yet ... how fun!). What you will have to do is, in your ShelfRepository, when you create the shelf, you will first have to go through all the books it contains and set the reference to the parent shelf as explained in [this article](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-onetomany-bidirectional-relationship/).
- Finally, regarding the "detached entity passed to persist" exception, Hibernate will always do that if you give it an object with its identity field populated, but the actual object was never fetched using Hibernate; if you are merely referencing an object in your JSON using the ID, you will have to first fetch the real entity from Hibernate and use that exact instance in your persistence.

I hope all this info will help you.